# Retrieve selecteditem combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

So I have a combobox

```
cmbSpecifics1.Items.AddRange(typeof(Aggressive).GetEnumNames());
```

That i populate with enum

```
public enum Aggressive
{
    Yes,
    No,
    Sometimes,
    Only_when_hungry
}
```

How do I retrieve its selected value and sending it to a property?

```
    public Aggressive RealAggressiveLevel
    {
        get { return _aggressive; }
        set { _aggressive = value; }
    }

    Bee iBee = new Bee(animal);
    iBee.RealAggressiveLevel = ???cmbSpecifics1.SelectedValue???
```

This is how i populate it:

```
lblSpecifics1.Text = "Aggressive:";
cmbSpecifics1.Items.Clear();
cmbSpecifics1.Items.AddRange(typeof(Aggressive).GetEnumNames());
```

This is the line I get null ref exception on

```
iBee.RealAggressiveLevel = (Aggressive)Enum.Parse(typeof(Aggressive), cmbSpecifics1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

this is how im adding data

```
_animal = ((AnimalType)lbCategory.SelectedIndex);
            switch (_animal)
            {
                case AnimalType.Insect:
                    switch ((InsectTypes)lbAnimalObject.SelectedIndex)
                    {
                        case InsectTypes.Bee:
                            Bee iBee = new Bee(animal);
                            iBee.RealAggressiveLevel = (Aggressive)Enum.Parse(typeof(Aggressive), cmbSpecifics1.SelectedValue.ToString());
                            iBee.Worker = tbSpecific1.Text;
                            iBee.Color = tbSpecific2.Text;
                            animalManager.Add(iBee);
                            break;
```

Cheers in advance

Comment: What environment is this in? Is it UWP, Windows Forms, WPF?

Comment: Windows Forms, sorry missed that

Comment: That solution would only works if it is acceptable to write actual `enum` value text such as "Only_when_hungry" in the UI which is not the case for most application and even less if you have to be multilingual. I would usually use an `Item` class to represent an item and use a resource file to load localized name using `ToString()` to get the text of the enum value as a key in the resource. And I would have some unit testing to ensure that I have no missing or extra entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `SelectedValue` to String and then use `Enum.Parse` to convert back to `Enum` `Aggressive`.

`ComboBox.SelectedValue` returns the `Object` and then it needs to converted to String as the Enum.Parse needs the String as an input. Also the return type is `object` so it needs to be converted again (Cast) to Enum. Below is the signature of `Enum.Parse` method.

```
public static object Parse(
    Type enumType,
    string value
)
```

So, following code should work for you.

```
 iBee.RealAggressiveLevel = (Aggressive) Enum.Parse(typeof(Aggressive), cmbSpecifics2.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: cheers, however it's giving me a null ref exception, cannot seem to figure out why

Comment: can you post more code and show which line is giving an error? If you have not selected anything, then `SelectedValue` can be null.

Comment: added some more code, idk what more that relates to it. i'm certain i am selecting an option in the combobox. Also I changed it to cmbSpecific1 (posted the wrong one first)

Comment: and which line is throwing exception ?

Comment: iBee.RealAggressiveLevel = (Aggressive) Enum.Parse(typeof(Aggressive), cmbSpecifics2.SelectedValue.ToString()); >>> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Noticed that even if I send another parameter iBee.RealAggressiveLevel = Aggressive.Only_when_hungry; it always chooses the first (Yes) in the enum, I cannot even make it change it manually (for some reason)

Comment: Use `cmbSpecifics1.SelectedItem` in place of the `cmbSpecifics1.SelectedValue` and let me know if you face the error.

Comment: works with selecteditem! please update ur code above for reference :) cheers

Comment: If you are binding the data using DataSource, then the `SelectedValue` would have worked, but you are adding the items, So `SelectedItem` would work in your case.